# Extract network user login in a java web application

Tags: java

Is there a way to extract the username logged into the network from a Java web-based application?

Comment: That answer depends much on the architecture of your application.  We need much more information.

Comment: With a windows application, we can extract the username logged into the network from HttpContext.Curret.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].   Is there a way to do the same from a java web-based application?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you simply trying to get the user logged in to the computer or are you running a Tomcat server and wish to know the user it is running as or something else? I think we need some more information to be able to answer.

Comment: I want to get the user logged in to the computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```